# 404 Not Found - "message": "Requested entity was not found." when requesting URI mybusinessaccountmanagement.googleapis.com

Tags: oauth2-playground

Help me to understand what the issue is.
As a manager I have access to a Business location, let's say with account ID 1111
I obtained a client ID within my Google Console.
I obtained the access to the Private My Business API to get Google Reviews as a 3rd party side (service provider).
When I use a playground on the https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground I have 200 OK when I request this URI: https://mybusinessaccountmanagement.googleapis.com/v1/accounts/ and it returns my business location and not the client's.
When I try to add client's account ID, let's say 1111
https://mybusinessaccountmanagement.googleapis.com/v1/accounts/1111
it returns 404 Not found.
The full response:

```
GET /v1/accounts/1111 HTTP/1.1
Host: mybusinessaccountmanagement.googleapis.com
Content-length: 0
Authorization: Bearer xxxx
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-length: 114
X-xss-protection: 0
X-content-type-options: nosniff
Transfer-encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin, X-Origin, Referer
Server: ESF
-content-encoding: gzip
Cache-control: private
Date: Tue, 12 Dec 2023 04:23:56 GMT
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000
Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
{
  "error": {
    "status": "NOT_FOUND", 
    "message": "Requested entity was not found.", 
    "code": 404
  }
}
```

What can be the issue? What am I missing?